# Paste visible cells error 1004

Tags: vba

I am trying to write some code that will take a sheet with a table and paste only the visible cells to a new worksheet and freeze the header row.  I keep getting a 1004 paste method of workseet class failed error, the debugger highlights activesheet.paste as the issue.  I'm fairly new to VBA so not sure why I'm getting an error on such a seemingly simple command?

```
    Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Midwest Log").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "MW Log"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("MW Log").Paste
    Columns("A:I").Select
    Columns("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Rows("4:4").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have `Application.CutCopyMode = False` in there. Remove it and you should be fine.

I took the liberty to clear up the selections. Selections are considered very bad style in excel VBA because they are slow and unreliable. You can usually get rid of them pretty easily by replacing

```
something.Select
Selection.dosomething
```

with

```
something.dosomething
```

The freezing was a little tricky though and I'm not sure it's the ideal way either.

```
Sheets("Midwest Log").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "MW Log"
Sheets("MW Log").Paste
Columns("A:I").AutoFit
ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 3
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

Comment: The code doesn't work, says excel can't process with available resources, then still gives an error message at the paste line.

Comment: Maybe it's your sheet? Does it contain a lot of data? If not, did you try it on a new/blank sheet?